# zero match display in group by

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

Query

```
SELECT 
   c.class_id,
   count(s.student_id) as total_students 
FROM 
   classes c
   LEFT JOIN students s ON c.class_id = s.class_id
GROUP BY c.class_id;
```

expected result

```
445 15
448 19
451  9
455 0
478 0
489 0
501 84
```

But this is the result of above query

```
445 15
448 19
451  9
455 0
501 84
```

if I suppress id:455 by the where clause, it shows 478 as 0. Somehow its grouping over the zero..

PS: its late at night and my brains are fried

---- EDIT ---
The solution below works but this doesn't: (added a condtion to filter students). This query eliminates all 0's

```
SELECT c.class_id,
       SUM
       (
        CASE
         WHEN s.student_id IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
        END
       ) as total_students 
  FROM classes c LEFT JOIN students s ON c.class_id = s.class_id WHERE s.student_type='instate'
GROUP BY c.class_id;
```

Comment: __PS: its late at night and my brains are fried__ - you have multiple brains, lucky you! :)

Comment: nope, just two; left and right !

Answer (score 1):

I guess the NULL values of `s.student_id` values in the `COUNT` aggregate function could be cause.

Try this version(`SUM` aggregate with a `CASE` statement):

```
SELECT c.class_id,
       SUM
       (
        CASE
         WHEN s.student_id IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE 1
        END
       ) as total_students 
  FROM classes c LEFT JOIN students s ON c.class_id = s.class_id
GROUP BY c.class_id;
```

Comment: cool, this works well, but when I add a condition related to students ex: WHERE s.student_tag='instate'; it goes back to the same result, except this time there is no 0 match.

Answer (score 0):

It counts students per class and after that `left join` them (`left` to select all classes not only those with students) to classes. `coalesce` returns `0` for classes without students for those `left join` returns `null`s.

```
select c.class_id, coalesce(s.total_students, 0) as total_students
from classes c
left join (
    select class_id, count(student_id) as total_students
    from students
    where student_type='instate'
    group by class_id
) s on c.class_id = s.class_id
```

Comment: @Stewie do you have indices on `class_id` in both tables? Do you have any indices?

Comment: yes, class_id and student_id both are primary keys. and there is an index on student type.

Comment: @Stewie index on `students.student_id` is useless in this case, useful could be an index on `students(class_id,student_type)`. How many rows are in `students` table?

Comment: about 7million in students and 140K in classes ! student_id is the primary key, so the index is obvious.  yes the above might help. let me look into that.. just that creating index on that would be a long downtime for the application (about 20-25 mins)